# Repeated measures ANOVA for case-control study

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, repeated-measures

I'm working with two groups - patients and controls - and we've collected data on 36 continuous measures (biological indexes) for each individual at 4 different time points. My primary focus is on identifying any differences in the means of these indexes between the two groups at each time point.

Initially, I was thinking of conducting a series of independent t-tests for each variable at each time point. However, someone suggested taking into account repeated measures ANOVA instead. Any thoughts or suggestions on which statistical approach would be more suitable for my study?

Would it be correct to use the Group as a between-subject factor and Time as a within-subjects factor?

The data would look like this:

```
| Subject | Group   | Time1 | Time2 | Time3 | Time4 |
| ------- | ------- | ----- | ----- | ----- | ----- |
| 1       | Patient | 15.2  | 16.5  | 14.8  | 17.2  |
| 2       | Patient | 14.5  | 15.8  | 14.2  | 16.5  |
| 3       | Patient | 16.8  | 17.3  | 16.5  | 18.1  |
| 4       | Control | 13.9  | 14.2  | 13.7  | 15.0  |
| 5       | Patient | 15.5  | 16.0  | 15.2  | 17.5  |
| ...     | ...     | ...   | ...   | ...   | ...   |
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly, separate t-tests would not be a good idea. If possible, you want to include all or most data into the same model. Repeated-measures ANOVA could be fine, using time as a within-person factor and group as a between-person factor as you suggest. Or a multilevel model with group*time interaction and random intercept of participant.

However, if you have 36 separate outcomes and you'll run a separate model for each, you are conducting quite many tests on the same datasets, and the reliability of your significance testing suffers. A classic advice would be to adjust your critical p-value as lower than it originally was, this is what I typically do in a similar situation, but I'm not a statistician and many statisticians disagree with p-value adjustment as a remedy for multiple comparisons, so you have to consider what route best applies to your situation.

One way would be to reduce the 36 dimensions into a smaller number (e.g. via factor analysis) or to use structural equation modeling or multilevel modeling to combine the different outcomes into the same model.

Comment: I decided to go for linear mixed effect model, though I do not get why it is a bad idea to use separate t-test. However, is it possible that I obtain very different results from the separate t-tests? E.g., for one variable I obtained a significant difference between groups at Time3 (after bonferroni correction, so pretty strong), but when modelling the same variable with lmm i do not see anymore that difference at the same time point. Which one should I trust?

Comment: I'm not the best to explain this, but 1) using separate t-tests instead of putting all data into the same model increases the risk of false positives (independently of the fact that running separate model for all 36 outcomes also increases that) and 2) when you run separate models for each time point, each model capitalizes on the specific features of the data from that time point, and the parameters across models may not be comparable and generalizable.

Comment: ...and you data from different time points is not independent, so you definitely should not use independent sample t-tests. You should trust the lmm results over the t-test results. Here are some resources that may help understanding the logic behind this: https://mattsosna.com/T-tests-vs-ANOVA/ and https://statistics.laerd.com/statistical-guides/one-way-anova-statistical-guide-2.php